# Select option only affects row one - php-jquery-mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

**Hi ! I used mysqli for my connection in database.[image]**
My problem is the second and the  following rows is not affected whenever I select new option in . 
Can you guys please help me to solve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
  $('#dealer').change(function () 
  {
   $("#tt").val($(this).val());
  }); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
  <tr>
   <th>USERNAME</th>
   <th>PASSWORD</th>
   <th>CURRENT USER TYPE</th>
   <th>CHANGE USER TYPE</th>
   <th>UPDATE</th>
   <th>DELETE</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($records))
  {
   //echo "<tr><form action='super_admin_function_edit.php' method='post'>";
   echo "<tr><form action=super_admin_function_edit.php method=post>";
   echo "<td><input type=text name=emp_username value='".$row['emp_username']."'></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=text name=emp_password value='".$row['emp_password']."'></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=text name=emp_type id=tt value='".$row['emp_type']."'></td>";
   
   //echo "<td><input type='text' id='tt' </td>";
   
   
   echo " <td><select name='dealer' id='dealer'>
      <option value='0'>---- select Dealer -----</option>
      <option value='1'>---- select Dealer1 -----</option>
      <option value='2'>---- select Dealer2 -----</option>     
     </select>
     </td>";
     
   echo "<input type=hidden name=emp_id value='".$row['emp_id']."'></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=submit></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=submit value=Delete></td>";
   echo "</form></tr>";
  }
  ?>

 </body>
```

Comment: Every row has an ID of `id=tt` which is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Id's cannot be duplicated on an HTML page. You have `id="tt"` and `id="dealer"` on each row and browsers only see the first of each on the page. The reason for this is that browsers have a fast-lookup dictionary, that contains one DOM element per key (per id)

Change it to use a `tt` class and `dealer` class and find the closest one to the `.dealer` select that changes (e.g. based on the tr/row).

eg. using:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('.dealer').change(function () 
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".tt").val($(this).val());
    }); 
});
```

notes:

- `$(function ()..` is just the preferred shortcut for `$(document).ready(function()...`

Answer (score 0):

Your generated markup will contain multiple **id** attributes with the same value, which is not valid HTML. So this jQuery code:

```
$("#tt").val($(this).val());
```

will only pick the first occurrence of the id. To fix this, replace `id=tt` with `class='tt'` and `id='dealer'` with `class='dealer'`.

Similarly, your jQuery code to:

```
$('.dealer').change(function () 
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.tt').val($(this).val());
    });
```